# Correctly getting angular service object reference when a function is invoked using Window object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function exposed on window object. This is getting invoked from my Windows Application.

```
window.patchTransaction = this.AngularService.myMethod.bind(this);
```

In AngularService.js

```
myMethod(val) {
window.alert(val); // argument i am passing from Windows appication
 window.alert(this); // undefined
}
```

How can i get this reference of AngularService inside myMethod?

Comment: What is the value of "this" when you call window.patchTransaction = this.AngularService.myMethod.bind(this) ?

Comment: It's a string which i am passing from Windows Application.

Comment: No - the value you're passing from Windows application will be "val", not "this". The "this" value will be whatever "this" is when you call .bind.

Comment: Inside of the function this is undefined which is the problem. I have other properties of this which i need to access.

Comment: Right. Which leads me back to my original question: when you call window.patchTransaction = ..., what is the value of "this"? (I'm not asking about the value of "this" *inside* myMethod. I'm asking what it is when you setup window.patchTransaction.)

Comment: It  will be the controller's reference where i have setup window object.

Comment: Are you sure? If you call myMethod from JavaScript, what is the value of *this*?

Comment: Have you tried this.AngularService.myMethod.bind(this, 'yourValue');

Comment: It should be object which is invoking the function.

Comment: I think i have some idea where you leading me into. Let me just check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly assigning Angular Service method to exposed window object.

In AngularController

```
window.patchTransaction = this.delegateMethod.bind(this);

delegateMethod(str) {
 this.AngularService.myMethod(str);
}
```